# how to filter an <option> value in ruby for quotes

Tags: ruby, filtering

Have a do loop in HTML supporting a Ruby app:

```
<% @list.each do |object| %>
    <option value="<%= object['name'] %>"><%= object['name'] %></option>
<% end %>
```

Would like to be able to filter the `<option value="<%= object['name'] %>">` item for quotes to preserve the final HTML -- is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a Rails app, then I'd suggest using one of the built-in helpers, like so:

```
options_for_select(@list.map{ |object| [object['name'], object['name']] })
```

If not, then maybe just gsub:

```
<option value="<%= object['name'].gsub("\"","") %>">
```

Comment: if the value and showing names are same, you need only this `options_for_select(@list.map { |l| l['name'] })`...if the `@list` is an array of objects that has a method `name`, it can be further simplified to `options_for_select(@list.map(&:name))`..and yeah..`options_for_select` is available if it is a Rails app.

Answer (score 1):

In pure Ruby, you can use [CGI::escapeHTML](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/CGI.html#method-c-escapeHTML), like this:

```
<% @list.each do |object| %>
    <% escaped_value = CGI::escapeHTML(object['name']) %>
    <option value="<%= escaped_value %>"><%= escaped_value %></option>
<% end %>
```

You will have to do a `require 'cgi'`, to use this.

If you are using Rails, you are better off using [options_for_select](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_for_select), or use the [select_tag](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-select_tag) or [select](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-select) according to your need, as the other answer specifies